# how to get value from application.yml in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

This is my application.yml file

```
aws:
  secretsManager:
    secretName: "test"
    region: "us-west-2"
```

I want get secretName and region from that yml file, but I failed with this code, can anyone help me with that?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws")

class GetSecretConfig {

    @Value("\${aws.secretsManager.secretName}")
    private val secretName: String? = null

    @Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}")
    private val region: String? = null
}
```

Comment: What's the failure you got? It injects those properties correctly with this setup.

Comment: Hi @Laksitha, I didn't get error, just can't get the value, it's return null

Comment: Is your `application.yml` formatted correctly? And do you have `plugin.spring`/`all-open` plugin in your gradle/maven config?

Comment: The application.yml above is all the thing in this file, and for plugin.spring, is this what you talking about, “spring-boot-maven-plugin”?

Comment: Have you tried declaring your variables using `lateinit var` without setting a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside of this approach is that you have to use `var` for constant values

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
class Config {
    var foo: String? = null
}
```

and it seams that this is your problem, you have only val, you should see errors / exceptions during startup.

A better way for Kotlin was implemented in this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762) and is documented here: [ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kotlin-configuration-properties)

Example taken from the Spring Docs:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("example.kotlin")
data class KotlinExampleProperties(
        val name: String,
        val description: String,
        val myService: MyService) {

    data class MyService(
            val apiToken: String,
            val uri: URI
    )
}
```

Here you have a data class with immutable val properties which represents config values in a much better way.